# How to use both Bootstrap 3 and Bootstrap 4 in one angular CLI project

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-cli, bootstrap-4

Can someone tell me how to install Bootstrap 3 and Bootstrap 4 in one angular cli project?

Comment: next time do some google first https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home

Comment: how to use both in one project with install using cli

Comment: install both manually and then import both, but be prepared to get a lot of conflicts

Answer (score -1):

There are different ways to install bootstrap on angular Application. either using CDN links or after downloading the module.

[Refer this blog for installation](https://www.ngdevelop.tech/bootstrap-installation/) for the Bootstrap 4 installation.
same way you can install Bootstrap 3.

but during the use of both bootstrap you might get conflicts in some css classes.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow community. Please take some time and complete [Welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide.